# Can't change font at all using .Xresources

Tags: fonts, gentoo, rxvt, x-resources

So I want to change the URxvt font which currently seems to be the X.Org Misc Fixed. I have tried adding the following to .Xresources:
`URxvt.font: xft:Fira Code:style=Retina:size=13`,
`URxvt.font: xft:Fira Code,Fira Code Retina:style=Retina:size=13`, and even
`URxvt.font: fixed:size=13`. I have tried many other fonts also. Besides, I have tried the `-fn` option of urxvt command, but only `fixed` seems to work. Everything else returns:
`urxvt: unable to load base fontset, please specify a valid one using -fn, aborting.`

Please help.
Thank you.
PS: I am on i3 and  Gentoo.
PPS: Output of `fc-list | grep Fira` https://pastebin.com/mNCfmQLE

Comment: Can someone tell me how to add a line break while writing a question?

Comment: Blank line in the text causes a line break

Comment: If you run `urxvt -h`, what does the `options: ` line say? Does it include `xft` (indicating that you have Xft font support compiled in)?

Comment: options: perl,styles,combining,encodings=eu+vn+jp+jp-ext+kr+zh+zh-ext,transparent,tint,XIM,frills,selectionscrolling,wheel,slipwheel,cursorBlink,pointerBlank,scrollbars=plain+rxvt+NeXT+xterm

Comment: Ahh :) recompile _with_ xft support, and then try using the lowercase variant in your `.Xresources`, that should work

Comment: @Michel What is the USE flag for that?

Comment: `xft` ;) (see also https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/x11-terms/rxvt-unicode)

Comment: @Michel Can you change your answer to include the above so I can mark it accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check to see if your urxvt includes Xft support by running `urxvt -h`, the `options:` line should include the string `xft` (thanks to the comment by telcoM for the suggestion).

If it doesn't, re-install it with `xft` added to your `USE` flags.

Then, add the following to your `~/.Xresources`:

```
urxvt*font: xft:Fira Code Retina:size=13
```